# Creating dummy date records between two date ranges

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Hello I need to create dummy date records per subjid. So for example 10001 start date (ASTDT) is 01DEC2019 and End date (AENDT) IS 03DEC2019 so I need to create a dummy record for 02DEC2019 for that subject ID. I'm assuming this may require a proc transpose at some point and I've seen relevant code with similar logic like this but not exactly what I need

```
data want;
set have;
by account;

output;

if last.account then do;
    /*Current month as a number*/
    month_n = month(input(catt("01",strip(month),"2000"),date9.));
    /*LastMonth as a number*/
    to_month = month(input(catt("01",lastMonth,"2000"),date9.));

    do i=month_n+1 to to_month;
        month = put(mdy(i,1,2000),monname3.); /*Increment the month and write the month name*/
        output;
    end;
end;

drop month_n to_month i;
run;
```

This is the desired output

```
100001 01DEC2019 03DEC2019
100001 02DEC2019 03DEC2019
100001 03DEC2019 03DEC2019
100002 30JAN2020 31JAN2020
100002 31JAN2020 31JAN2020
100002 31JAN2020 02FEB2020
100002 01FEB2020 02FEB2020
100002 02FEB2020 02FEB2020
100002 31JAN2020 31JAN2020
100003 24FEB2020 24FEB2020
100003 21FEB2020 22FEB2020
100003 22FEB2020 22FEB2020
```

Comment: I'm unsure of what you really want here. Do you want one record for each date in between ASTDT and AENDT including those two?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I need

Comment: Then what if there are multiple obs with the same SUBJID? Do you want to start with min(ASTDT) and end at max(AENDT) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data want(drop = ASTDT);
   format subjid dt AENDT;
   set have;
   do dt = ASTDT to AENDT;
      dummy = not (dt = ASTDT | dt = AENDT);
      output;
   end;
   format dt date9.;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs subjid dt        AENDT     dummy 
1   100001 01DEC2019 03DEC2019 0 
2   100001 02DEC2019 03DEC2019 1 
3   100001 03DEC2019 03DEC2019 0 
4   100002 30JAN2020 31JAN2020 0 
5   100002 31JAN2020 31JAN2020 0 
6   100002 31JAN2020 02FEB2020 0 
7   100002 01FEB2020 02FEB2020 1 
8   100002 02FEB2020 02FEB2020 0 
9   100002 31JAN2020 31JAN2020 0 
10  100003 24FEB2020 24FEB2020 0 
11  100003 21FEB2020 22FEB2020 0 
12  100003 22FEB2020 22FEB2020 0
```

Comment: wait is that right?. Where is the 02dec 03dec dummy records for 02dec2019 and 03dec2019 in ASTDT for the first date range?

Comment: Sorry, just edited.

Comment: Rename dt as you like

Comment: ah I get you thanks :)

Comment: additonal to the question being asked can I apply a similar do loop for start day (stdy) and end day (endy) to populate corresponding days for the dummy records. If so is it before the first output statement

Answer (score 1):

For starters, let us assunme that your data looks like below.

What does your desired result look like?

```
data have;
input subjid $ (ASTDT AENDT)(:date9.);
format ASTDT AENDT date9.;
datalines;
100001 01DEC2019 03DEC2019
100002 30JAN2020 31JAN2020
100002 31JAN2020 02FEB2020
100002 31JAN2020 31JAN2020
100003 24FEB2020 24FEB2020
100003 21FEB2020 22FEB2020
;
```

Comment: I updated my question with the desired output using your example data as reference

Answer (score 1):

See if this meets your needs

```
data have;
input subjid $ (ASTDT AENDT)(:date9.);
format ASTDT AENDT date9.;
datalines;
100001 01DEC2019 03DEC2019
100002 30JAN2020 31JAN2020
100002 31JAN2020 02FEB2020
100002 31JAN2020 31JAN2020
100003 24FEB2020 24FEB2020
100003 21FEB2020 22FEB2020
;

data want;
   set have;
   do ASTDT = ASTDT to AENDT;
      output;
   end;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs subjid ASTDT     AENDT 
1   100001 01DEC2019 03DEC2019 
2   100001 02DEC2019 03DEC2019 
3   100001 03DEC2019 03DEC2019 
4   100002 30JAN2020 31JAN2020 
5   100002 31JAN2020 31JAN2020 
6   100002 31JAN2020 02FEB2020 
7   100002 01FEB2020 02FEB2020 
8   100002 02FEB2020 02FEB2020 
9   100002 31JAN2020 31JAN2020 
10  100003 24FEB2020 24FEB2020 
11  100003 21FEB2020 22FEB2020 
12  100003 22FEB2020 22FEB2020
```

Comment: This is great but is there a way to flag or distinguish which records are dummy records?

Comment: Sure thing. See my new reply